# Get Location of Saved Camera Picture

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Okay, so I have an onclick on a button that opens the camera, when I take a picture and save it how do I get the file name+location of where it was saved to open it in my app?

Here is my button click

```
Button btncamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncamera);
btncamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent cameraIntent = nwe Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2500);
    }
}
```

Here is my Result it doesn't contain anything, but it will start another Intent to display the image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

}
```

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but any guidance would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your onActivityResult.

```
Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Take the image out of the camera intent, create a bitmap out of it, and then use it from there. Write it to a file, or import it directly into a display resource.
Also be sure to check your ResultCode to determine if a picture actually has been taken.